# Camel No Route when Autowiring Constructor

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

Im using spring boot with modules.  I have a parent project with several sub modules.

Camel Routes are failing to start up when I configure the route with Contructor Autowiring.

I get `Total 0 routes, of which 0 are started`When starting constructor like this.

```
private final ScanProcessor scanProcessor;
private final ScheduleProcessor scheduleProcessor;
private final TagProcessor tagProcessor;
private final LatestScanProcessor latestScanProcessor;
private final RabbitMqService rabbitMqService;

@Autowired
public DashboardRoute(ScanProcessor scanProcessor,
                      ScheduleProcessor scheduleProcessor,
                      TagProcessor tagProcessor,
                      LatestScanProcessor latestScanProcessor,
                      RabbitMqService rabbitMqService){
    this.scanProcessor = scanProcessor;
    this.scheduleProcessor = scheduleProcessor;
    this.tagProcessor = tagProcessor;
    this.latestScanProcessor = latestScanProcessor;
    this.rabbitMqService = rabbitMqService;
}

@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
           from(CONSUME_SCHEDULE_ROUTE)
            .routeId("consume-schedule")
            .process(scheduleProcessor);  // no strings
}
```

The whole thing works when I dont autowire any of the beans and delcare the route like this.

```
 from(CONSUME_SCHEDULE_ROUTE)
   .routeId("consume-schedule")
   .process("scheduleProcessor")  // notice this is a string
```

Does camel support spring route Contructor autowiring? Do I need to take some extra config steps to handle this properly?  I prefer linking beans directly that way when I refactor class names it links back ok.

Comment: 1. Can you put the class declaration with Annotation
2. With constructor injection, are the fields initialized and does configure method gets executed?

Comment: not sure what you mean by does configure method gets executed?

Comment: when you debug your application, does control come to configure methos?

Comment: not sure what configure method I would be looking at...  The route extends route builder and that has many methods.. wouldnt know which one.

Comment: Have you had a look at the [Camel Spring-Boot support documentation](http://camel.apache.org/spring-boot.html) yet? You probably should add how you define your processor as beans, maybe the configuration isn't considered during the start?

Comment: You need to show the entire class declaration. Annotation based spring depends on more than just the method level.

Comment: @Stephan could you expand on this a bit more please?

Comment: @Robbo_UK take a look at Reedwanul's answer. See how he includes the annotations on the class, not just the methods? You should add the class declaration to your code snippet so we can be sure that you havent forgotten an annotation at that level.

Comment: @Robbo_UK which was the solution in the end ? Adding Autowired at the level of each class variable saved the day ? (as per Reedwanul Islam's response)

Answer (score 1):

I tried similar example as yours and it worked correctly. You can make sure that you have @Compoent in you route class and all the processor classes and service class.

Also you can try to add @Autowired on the local variable. (Constructor should work fine. This is just an extra stap to make sure your constructor works)

```
@Component
@ServletComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.camel")
public class ServiceRoutes extends RouteBuilder { 

    @Autowired
    private ScanProcessor scanProcessor;
    @Autowired
    private  ScheduleProcessor scheduleProcessor;
    @Autowired
    private TagProcessor tagProcessor;
    @Autowired
    private LatestScanProcessor latestScanProcessor;
    @Autowired
    private RabbitMqService rabbitMqService;

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
               from(CONSUME_SCHEDULE_ROUTE)
                .routeId("consume-schedule")
                .process(scheduleProcessor); 
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: In your route if you just do 'new ScheduleProcessor()' does it start?

Comment: Also make sure you have @Component with ScheduleProcessor class.